# NativeScript ObservableArray's .length in an expression

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I have a view-model with an `ObservableArray`. In the .xml file I have code that relies on the `.length` of the mentioned array:

```
<Button text="should disappear" tap="tapped" visibility="{{items.length === 0 ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}"></Button>
```

Here's the code-behind

```
let model: ViewModel;

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {

    let page = <Page>args.object;

    model = new ViewModel();
    page.bindingContext = model;
}

export function tapped() {
    console.log("adding an item");
    model.addItem()
}

class ViewModel {
    public items: ObservableArray<number>;

    constructor() {
        this.items = new ObservableArray<number>([])
    }

    public addItem() {
        this.items.push(Math.random())
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if I add items to the array, the button is still visible. Here's a [repo](https://github.com/jorotenev/ns-data-binding-issue) with the runnable app.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks :)